# C++ Template - No viable conversion error

Tags: c++, templates, point-cloud-library

I'm now dealing with template in c++ with PCL (Point Cloud Library) and I encountered something that I'm not able to solve (I searched before on the internet and on Stack)

I have a template class called `Features`.

my hpp file:

```
#ifndef KeyFeatures_hpp
#define KeyFeatures_hpp

// Declarations and includes

typedef pcl::PointXYZRGB PointTypeRGB;
template<typename FeatureType>
class Features {

public:
    Features(const int typeDescriptor);

 void setDescriptorExtractor(typename  pcl::Feature<PointTypeRGB, FeatureType>::Ptr extractor);

private:
    typename pcl::Feature<PointTypeRGB, FeatureType>::Ptr m_descriptor_extractor;


};

#endif /* Features_hpp */
```

In the cpp file I have a constructor which will checks what kind of type is it and then perform some action.

```
template <typename FeatureType>
Features<FeatureType>::Features(const int type){
       //Some code

if (type == DESCRIPTOR_SHOT){
    pcl::SHOTEstimationOMP<PointTypeRGB, pcl::Normal, pcl::SHOT352>* shot = new pcl::SHOTEstimationOMP<PointTypeRGB, pcl::Normal, pcl::SHOT352>;
    shot->setRadiusSearch (0.02f);

    pcl::Feature<PointTypeRGB, pcl::SHOT352>::Ptr descriptor_extractor (shot);
    descriptor_extractor->setSearchMethod (pcl::search::Search<PointTypeRGB>::Ptr (new pcl::search::KdTree<PointTypeRGB>));

    this->m_descriptor_extractor = descriptor_extractor;//ERROR
    setDescriptorExtractor(descriptor_extractor);//ERROR

       // Some code
}
```

The error appeared in the last two lines when I try without success to fill in my variable member.
Each time I have the following error x 10 (corresponding to my 10 kind of type)

```
error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'const shared_ptr<pcl::Feature<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::SHOT352> >'
to 'this_type' (aka 'shared_ptr<pcl::Feature<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::ShapeContext1980> >')
```

However at the end of my cpp file I put all my template class. For example:

```
template class Features<pcl::SHOT352>;
```

In my main function I called this class by using:

```
Features<pcl::SHOT352> feature_SHOT(type);
```

It seems that it's not able to perform the conversion..

Can someone might be able to help me ?

Thank

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are instantiating `Features<pcl::ShapeContext1980>` so its `m_descriptor_extractor` has the type `pcl::Feature<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::ShapeContext1980>::Ptr` which is `shared_ptr<pcl::Feature<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::ShapeContext1980>>`.

But inside the constructor you are still using `pcl::Feature<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::SHOT352>::Ptr`, that is `shared_ptr<pcl::Feature<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::SHOT352>>` - a totally different type.

And as a side note, [you generally don't implement templates in .cpp files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/3959454).

Comment: I edited my code. I constructed my Feature object with a specific type (here SHOT one) that's why I don't understand why I have this error 10 times corresponding to my 10 others descriptors.

Concerning the template, I did that because otherwise my hpp file will be huge...And I wanted to keep clean.

Comment: Because you do the same thing (with the wrong specific type) in all the 10 other descriptors.

Comment: But when I constructed my object I called it in this way  KeyFeatures<pcl::SHOT352> feature_SHOT(type) ; so here the type is well specified and therefore in my constructor it should created the appropriate type no ?

Comment: Did you read the link as to why templates need to go in headers?  If you want to keep things clean, put the template methods in a .inl file ("inline"), and then include the .inl file in the header.  (If you explicitly instantiate the templates, then that prevents others instantiating the templates with their types.  That's a loss of flexibility, but if you don't need the flexibility, then don't worry about it.)

Comment: @lilouch: You are explicitly instantiating the templates, so *all* methods are generated, and while your explicit type is fine for SHOT352, it doesn't work for ShapeContext1980

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the official term is a "class template" - a template for creating classes.

You appear to have created a class called `Features<pcl::ShapeContext1980>`.

This has `m_descriptor_extractor` of type `shared_ptr<pcl::Feature<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::ShapeContext1980> >`

You are trying to assign a `shared_ptr<pcl::Feature<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::SHOT352>>` to it.

They are completely unrelated types, so it fails *at compile time*.

Comment: No that's the point, I  didn't instantiate Features<pcl::ShapeContext1980> I just call template class Features<pcl::ShapeContext1980> at the end of my CPP file.

Comment: OK.  We need to see a [mcve].  Either your compiler has a serious bug, or you did instantiate Features<pcl::ShapeContext1980> .  I am betting on the latter.  Do you have a line `template class Features<pcl::ShapeContext1980>;`?  That instantiates it.

Comment: Yes at the end of my Features cpp file I called template class Features<pcl::ShapeContext1980> and for every type (About 10) in total !

Comment: Right.  So that specific line *does* instantiate the template, and it instantiates *all* of the methods in the template.

Comment: Okey I understand but if I don't put these lines, I cannot instantiate my other types. For example for another type if I call Features<pcl::FPFHSignature33> feature_FPFH(type); My compiler will say Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Features<pcl::FPFHSignature33>::Features(int)" So how I can manage that ?

Comment: Can you ever pass DESCRIPTOR_SHAPE_CONTEXT to the constructor of a `Features<pcl::SHOT352>`?  If not, I *suspect* that you need to create a `DescriptorExtractor` template function (with no body), and then explicitly specialize it for each of the feature types.  The constructor of `Features` would look like `Features() : m_descriptor_extractor(DescriptorExtractor<FeatureType>()) {}`

Comment: I did what you mentioned that is to say make specialization of my constructor and ... it works ! Thank you ! I learned something :).